# Same method signature for two diff methods in web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

it might have duplicate but i didn't find right solution,

My web api,

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    public string hello(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

my webapiconfig,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

my problem is

When i call http://localhost:1234/api/Sample/5 it's hitting Get(int id) but how can i call method 2 i.e hello(int id) ?? what needs to be changed and what's the best way to handle these kind of scenarios ??

Comment: Do you want to call `hello` method or `Gcccet`

Comment: To call hello method... http://localhost:1234/api/Sample/hello/5 ...

Comment: @Mittal, hello(int id) not hitting with  localhost:1234/api/Sample/hello/5

Comment: Change the routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: Okay, so if a GET to `http://localhost:1234/api/Sample/5` is meant to hit `hello`, how is `Get` meant to be accessed?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, I want call these two methods, what would be urls for these and any routing has to be added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

If you want to reference individual actions in your Web API then change your routing to this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you can access your action like this: localhost/api/{controller}/{action}/. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) for further information, especially ["Routing by Action Name"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-by-action-name).

**Orig:**

You seem to expect the same behaviour as with MVC Controllers. The Standard-Routing for MVC-Controller is this:

```
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

This corresponds to the name of the controller, the method which is to be used and some form of input. ApiControllers Route differently:

```
routeTemplate: "staticPart/{controller}/{id}"
```

As you can see there is only a reference to the individual controller and the input, as well as the "staticPart" which normally is something like /api/

The Idea is that you use a RESTful approach, connecting methods with different types of http methods (eg. DELETE, GET, POST, PUSH and PUT)

The Get Method in your example is a special because through the name "Get" you have told the compiler that this method corresponds with HTTP-GET.

So to get to your question: Either you change your Routing to that of MVC-Controller. So that you reference individual actions in your requests or you use different HTTP-Methods. Or you set routes indivdually as shown by [MaxB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989785/8471295)

You can find an official overview on Web API routing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/) There you'll find examples on all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem right, but if I did:

You should specify the route for the function not in its name, but in some other way. From my little experience with the topic, that's how I do it:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("SystemInfo")] // That's the name of the route you will call
public IHttpActionResult SystemInfo()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Consider checking [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) out.

So, considering your question, it would be like so:

```
[Route("Get")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}

[Route("hello")]
public string hello(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Comment: so what would be the urls for consumption of both methods ?